# Unable to Install Pillow for Tkinter via PIP

Tags: python, powershell, tkinter

I tried to install **Pillow** library for my Tkinter project but when I try to install it, it gives me the following error.

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install Pillow : The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have the latest Python version from the official website and I also have pip manually installed during my Win7 days. Even debugging ain't helping. It gives the same error.

Comment: are u using venv?

Answer (score 0):

are you using "pip" or "conda"?

try

```
conda install pillow
```

or

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: I am using pip, the official package manager of Python.

Comment: have you added `pip` and `python` into environmental variables?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this. Python is added to PATH but pip, not sure about that.  Will just check and let you know

Comment: @cyph3r.exe are you using virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need unofficial python binaries version of pillow. Go to this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow). Then press `F3`. then in search box, type `pillow`. then click on the hyperlink which is highlighted by the browser. then download a `wheel` according to your os and python version. after download, open cmd in the download folder. to do that press `SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK` and click on `Open CMD Here`. then on the cmd, type `pip3 install <your downloaded file name>` It should work. I used this trick for Installing `PyAudio` in Python 3.10 on Windows 10.
TIP: while typing 3/4 letters of the file name, press `TAB` to autocomplete

Comment: I tried your method brother but it seems it didn't work as expected. ```pip3 install .\Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip3.exe" install .\Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl': The system cannot find the file specified.```

Comment: Bro Its your file path error. `The system cannot find the file specified`. Another way-> right click on that downloaded file, click on propertise. then go to "details" tab. you will find the full path of the file at top of the window. copy that path, then open cmd. type command: `pip3 install "<Your file path>"` don't forget to add the path in double quote mark.